# Help on Resizing a Photoshop document w/layers for print!

Tags: adobe-photoshop, packaging, print-production

I hope someone can help me.

I am creating packaging for a client, and I decided to create the file bigger than the die line. So the dieline lets say is 11x9.5 inches and I just scaled the vector dieline bigger in my photoshop file to be able to work on a bigger canvas. I did this because i was editing alot of illustration drawings and wanted to be able to copy and paste them into different projects in the future without losing quality. I figured once I would be done with the project I could always change the size of the document and image to the correct size for the client.

So now it's done, but I have alot of problems!

When I change the image size, alot of the effects, strokes and gradients are changing from the original design!
I tried to create the whole layer into a smart object but the gradient mask I created also changed from the original design.

The client wants the file in the 11.5x9 cm plus a 1/8 inch bleed format, and currently my design looks like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zxvf2fyak77mu7s/Screenshot%202013-11-29%2018.28.31.png

Can someone please help on how to get this document scaled down? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Also, i forgot to add that the client wants this file editable... so thats the issue... if thats not possible, how could i get this file ready for print in the easiest way possible?

Comment: Photoshop is simply the *wrong* tool for this. You should be using Illustrator or InDesign. If you have vector elements they should scale fine, but all layer styles will need to be adjusted after scaling. As for supplying an editable file, that's another matter entirely.

Comment: I had to use photoshop - its all custom illustrations that wouldnt render properly in illustrator...

Comment: This seems like a bit of an unusual situation. Did you get it sorted?

Comment: Can you flatten it, THEN scale? It wouldn't be editable for the client, but unless they asked for that up front and that was part of the project, there shouldn't be any expectation that they were getting an editable file in the first place (when I work with clients that want editable work-files, I need to charge more because I need to make the files a whole lot more organized for future updating--which takes time and effort).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just merge the layers together and then scale it down? It will rasterize all strokes and effects etc.

You could also experiment when saving with `Bicubic Smoother/Sharper` etc to see which gives you the best result.